# how to do a planing with the sample function

Tags: r

I am trying to make a 4 days planing with a some conditions and I have some troubles to do it.

I have 15 people and 5 different tasks: CA (1 people needed), CB (1 poeple needed), G (4 people needed), S (2 people needed) and T (the rest of the people).

Some people cannot do some task. For each task I have a vector with the people ID that can do the task as shown below.

```
CA = seq(1:6)
CB = ses(1:6)
G  = seq(1:15)
S  = seq(2:15)
Tt = c(1,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13, 14, 15)
```

I have tried with the G task by building this data frame.
I would like now to add the S task but I don't know how to sample in a "new vector S" that do not contain the value already present in the G1-G4 variables (for a day).

Another thing that I would like to manage is to reduce the number of day a personne will do the G task or the S task (ex: if the poeple 3 did G on day 1, I would like to sample another people for day2, day3 and day4 when possible (it may not be always possible when I will take into account the day off).

```
Jour=c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3", "Day4")

planing= tibble(Jour)

planing_2= planing %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Gtask = paste(sample(G,4), collapse=";")) %>% 
  separate(Gtask, into=c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"))


> planing_2
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Jour  G1    G2    G3    G4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 J1    15    3     17    2    
2 J2    4     1     10    8    
3 J3    8     4     10    17   
4 J4    11    18    8     7   

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  Jour  G1    G2    G3    G4    S1    S2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <lgl>
1 J1    15    3     17    2     NA    NA   
2 J2    4     1     10    8     NA    NA   
3 J3    8     4     10    17    NA    NA   
4 J4    11    18    8     7     NA    NA
```

I may go totally in the wrong direction as I never did any automatic planing.
If there is another better way to start, I would take any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I would do it, where you just change one number to generate more days.

```
library(tidyverse)
CA = 1:6
CB = 1:6
G  = 1:15
S  = 2:15
Tt = c(1,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15) 

Jour = paste("Day", 1:4, sep = " ")
# Increase days by changing 4.

Tasks <- c("CA", "CB",
           paste("S", 1:2, sep = "_"),
           paste("Tt", 1:7, sep = "_"),
           paste("G", 1:4, sep = "_"))

dayplan <- function() {
  arrangement <- c()
  arrangement <- append(arrangement, sample(CA, 1))
  arrangement <- append(arrangement, sample(CB[!(CB %in% arrangement)], 1))
  arrangement <- append(arrangement, sample(S[!(S %in% arrangement)], 2))
  arrangement <- append(arrangement, sample(Tt[!(Tt %in% arrangement)], 7))
  arrangement <- append(arrangement, G[!(G %in% arrangement)])
  arrangement
}
# This function needs to change if you want nicer scalability
# with regards to tasks.

planning = tibble(
  rep(Jour, each = length(Tasks),
  rep(Tasks, length(Jour)),
  as.vector(replicate(length(Jour), dayplan()))
  )
colnames(planning) <- c("Jour", "Task", "Person_ID")

# planning is in "tidy" format (better for analyses)
# To get it into the format you presented, the following is required.
planning %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Task, values_from = Person_ID)
```

This does not address the issue regarding people doing tasks "G" and "S" on consecutive days as that is probably beyond the scope of what most people need.

In order to resolve that issue, you probably need to create some function that runs `dayplan()` over again until satisfactory, or better yet, create a deterministic function that plans the next day based on the previous one.